# python code for existing node chain blender

Tags: python, node-editor

I have created a complicated Cycles material with the node editor.  I am currently building a python script to recreate this material.   Is there any way to "export" python to create a material I have already made in the node editor?

Comment: Do you need to use python to re-create it? You can [append or link](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html) the material to another file.

Answer (score 1):

[I have written a tool for that](https://github.com/kilbee/NodeTreeProcTools), but it has only features I needed for my nodetrees. The code is ugly, but might give some pointers for you in case you'd want to write something like that yourself. Maybe there are other - more complete - tools like that I'm not aware of.